# How to serialize a POCO with desired property names

Tags: c#, xml, restsharp

This should be simple, but clearly I am missing the trick. I have a POCO:

```
public class job
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public string companywebsite { get; set; }

    public string[] locations { get; set; }
}
```

I am serializing it to XML with RestSharp. I am hoping to get either:

```
<job>
    <title>Hello title</title>
    <company>Hello company</company>
    <locations>New York</locations>
    <locations>Los Angeles</locations>
    <locations>Detroit</locations>
</job>
```

Or ideally...

```
<job>
    <title>Hello title</title>
    <company>Hello company</company>
    <locations>
         <location>New York</location>
         <location>Los Angeles</location>
         <location>Detroit</location>
    </locations>
</job>
```

But instead am getting this:

```
<job>
    <title>Hello title</title>
    <company>Hello company</company>
    <locations>
         <String />
         <String />
         <String />
    </locations>
</job>
```

Clearly the POCO needs to be different. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify the XmlSerializer behavior with Attributes

```
public class job
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public string companywebsite { get; set; }
    [XmlArray("locations")]
    [XmlArrayItem("location")]
    public string[] locations { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does RestSharp behave the same way as the framework's XmlSerializer?

Comment: if it doesn't it probably should ;)

Comment: Thanks, this didn't address the RestSharp issue, but I just went back to the framework version and your suggestion worked.